# Get primary keys from MSI table using msi.dl in c#

Tags: c#, com, windows-installer

I have a problem with calling `get_PrimaryKeys()` function from `msi.dll` in c#.
I want to fund out what are the primary keys in a given MSI table. I use the following code:

```
Type installerType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
installer = (Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(installerType);
database = installer.OpenDatabase(MSIPath, MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);
WindowsInstaller.Record data = null;     
data = database.PrimaryKeys[tableName];
string s = data.get_StringData(1);
```

If I use `database.get_PrimaryKeys(tableName)`, it gives the same error which is:

```
COMexception
Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
```

When I use other functions form msi.dll they works fine.

What is the problem?

Comment: it throws this exception at the line when I am calling 
`data = database.PrimaryKeys[tableName];'
or
`database.get_PrimaryKeys(tableName)`
where the table name is a string, for example "Property" so I do not get any Raecord object in return :(

Comment: and it does accept an argument, the documentation is wrong. [link]http://i.imgur.com/2VNZx.jpg

Comment: but it may not be a table name but something else, you may be right. :-)

Comment: Hmm, actually yes - you're right the documentation does have a section for the property parameter it just leaves it out of the syntax example :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an easier way to query MSI database from C# code. The [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) includes a well-designed convenient .NET API called DTF (Deployment Tools Foundation), which makes is possible to write the following (C#):

```
  using (var database = new Database("path\\to\\package.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.ReadOnly))
  {
    var table = database.Tables["someTableName"];
    foreach (var column in table.PrimaryKeys)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The table {0} defines {1} as primary key", table.Name, column);
    }
  }
```

All you have to do:

- install [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/releases)
- reference `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll` in your C# project
- add `using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;` namespace

You don't have to build your MSI with WiX in order to get advantage out of DTF. Reference DTF.chm (installed together with WiX) to know more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the official MSI-sample code from Microsoft here
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiTextIn.vbs

I also did a couple of tests with that VBS-samples and it turns out, that the table-name needs EXACTLY as listed in the MSI. E.g. 'file' will not work, but 'File'. It is case-sensitive!

Here a small PS-snippet that shows the sequence:

```
$installer = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$msi = 'c:\windows\installer\MySampleFile.MSI'
$db  = $installer.OpenDatabase($msi, 0)
$keys = $db.PrimaryKeys('Media')
$keys.StringData(1)
```

Returns "DiskId" as the PrimaryKey-columns for that table.